# Kendo UI cascading dropdownlist inside ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui

What I have is a parent kendo ui dropdown list and a child. I want cascading to work which does work. Problem is I need it to work in ng-repeat
Sample Dataset:

```
$scope.Doctypes = [
    {"Area": "parent01", "docType": "child01ofParent01", "docDrawer": "grandchild01ofParent01" },
    {"Area": "parent01", "docType": "child02ofParent01", "docDrawer": "grandchild02ofParent01" },
    {"Area": "parent01", "docType": "child03ofParent01", "docDrawer": "grandchild03ofParent01" },
    {"Area": "parent02", "docType": "child01ofParent02", "docDrawer": "grandchild01ofParent02" },
    {"Area": "parent02", "docType": "child02ofParent02", "docDrawer": "grandchild02ofParent02" },
    {"Area": "parent02", "docType": "child03ofParent02", "docDrawer": "grandchild03ofParent02" },
    {"Area": "parent03", "docType": "child01ofParent03", "docDrawer": "grandchild01ofParent03" },
    {"Area": "parent03", "docType": "child02ofParent03", "docDrawer": "grandchild02ofParent03" },
    {"Area": "parent04", "docType": "child01ofParent04", "docDrawer": "grandchild01ofParent04" },
    {"Area": "parent04", "docType": "child02ofParent04", "docDrawer": "grandchild02ofParent04" }
];
```

Next I have kendo Custom options for each dropdown list as follow.

```
    $scope.docTypeAreaCustomOptions = {
    autobind:true,
    filter:"contains",
    dataSource: $scope.Doctypes,
    dataTextField: "Area",
    dataValueField: "Area",
    optionLabel:"Select a Document Type Area"
};
$scope.docTypeCustomOptions = {
    autobind: false,
    filter:"contains",
    dataSource: $scope.Doctypes,
    dataTextField: "docType",
    dataValueField: "docType",
    cascadeFrom:"selectedDTA",//This is the id from the first(parent) dropdown list.
    optionLabel:"Select a Document Type",
};
```

In my View I have the following HTML:

```
 <tr data-ng-repeat="file in files">
                <td style="text-align:left;background-color:transparent;width:25px">
                    <input alt="Delete Document" height="20px" width="20px" type="image" src="delete.png" data-ng-click="delete(file, $event, $index)"/>
                    <!--<button data-ng-click="delete(file, $event, $index)">Delete</button>-->
                     &nbsp; {{ file.name }}</td>
                <td>
                        <select kendo-drop-down-list 
                         id="selectedDTA"
                         data-ng-model="file.selectedDocTypeArea" 
                         data-ng-change="onChange(file,$event,$index)"                   
                         style="width:200px;" 
                         k-options="docTypeAreaCustomOptions"
                         >
                        </select>
                         <br><span class="edmcError" data-ng-show="!file.selectedDocTypeArea">required</span>
                 </td>
                <td> 
                        <select kendo-drop-down-list
                         id="selectedDT"
                         data-ng-model="file.selectedDocType" 
                         k-options="docTypeCustomOptions"
                         data-ng-change="onChange(file,$event,$index)"           
                         style="width:200px;" 
                         >
                        </select>
                        <br><span class="edmcError" data-ng-show="!file.selectedDocType">required</span>

                 </td>
            </tr>
```

In the ng-repeat it thinks every parent is the same since the id field. so when you pick the first parent it sets the child for each row.

Thanks
Joe

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the solution. I moved all the code from the customoptions to inside the view.
parent dropdownlist

```
<select kendo-drop-down-list
                        name="documentTypeArea" 
                        id="selectedDTA{{$index}}"
                        data-ng-model="file.ddlDTA" 
                        style="width:200px;"
                        k-data-source="docTypes"
                        k-data-text-field="'Area'"
                        k-data-value-field="'Area'"
                        k-filter="'contains'"
                        k-option-label="'Select a Document Type Area'">
                        </select>
```

child dropdownlist

```
                            <select kendo-drop-down-list
                        name="documentType" 
                        data-ng-model="file.ddlDT" 
                        k-data-source="docTypes"
                        k-data-text-field="'docType'"
                        k-data-value-field="'docType'"
                        k-filter="'contains'"
                        k-cascade-from="'selectedDTA{{$index}}'"
                        k-option-label="'Select a Document Type'"
                        >
                        </select>
```